# Why Request.InputStream contains extra byte?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, ashx

I am uploading byte array to ASHX handler

```cs
byte[] serializedRequest = SerializeRequest();

var uri = new Uri(_server.ActionUrl);
using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
{
    client.UploadData(uri, serializedRequest);
}
```

Which is received by handler

```vb
Dim str As Stream = context.Request.InputStream
Dim transformation(str.Length - 1) As Byte ' here I have extra "0"-byte
str.Position = 0
str.Read(transformation, 0, transformation.Length)
```

As you see, I have to do `str.Length - 1` to declare byte array. And this is in development. I don't even know how it will behave when deployed. Where does this byte come from? Is this a reliable way or should I add some bytes at the start of the stream to tell how many bytes to read from Request.InputStream?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Dim x(y) as Byte` actually means "array with upper bound y (length = y + 1)" ([Arrays in VB.NET](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wak0wfyt.aspx)).

`Dim transformation(str.Length) As Byte` actually declares larger array than you need, so `str.Length - 1` statement is correct.

There is really no 0-value byte, because `Stream.Read()` does not need to read stream to the end (check method return value) and leaves extra byte with default (0) value.

Comment: You are totally right!! This is my VB glitch! Thank you